Appium: Android: Unable to Scroll towards the selected accessibility id
Using:
 driver.findElement(new AppiumBy.ByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(text(\"See More\"));"));
and Getting and Error: 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
using the right 'accessibility id' but still unable to scroll
Should be scroll to the 'See' more element. Also, There are too many 'see more' elements in the app so i know and i am missing this but this is n't the case i've also tried the unique text
